# Why is sin(1/x) not differentiable when x = 0?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, trigonometry

I know that when x = 0, the function is not differentiable. I also understand that as x approaches 0 from both sides the graph oscillates more rapidly causing the slope to equal infinity. However, I don't know how would you tie that into when x = 0, that's what causes it to be non-differentiable.

Comment: A differentiable function must be continuous.

Comment: In order to assess differentiability at $0$, you need to give a value to the function at $0$. for any value you'll assign to $f(0)$, you'll see that $\limsup\limits_{x\to 0}\left\lvert\frac{\sin\frac1x-f(0)}x\right\rvert=\infty$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that f(x) = $\sin(\frac1x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788227/show-that-fx-sin-frac1x-is-not-differentiable-at-x-0)

Answer (score 2):

A differentiable function must be continuous. This function hasn't a limit at $x=0$ and is thus not continuous. It has no limit at $x=0$ because, for every $\delta > 0$, there exist $x, y \in [-\delta, \delta]$ s.t. $f(x)=1, f(y)=-1$.

So, If you choose $\epsilon < 1$, for every $\delta > 0$, It doesn't hold that $x \in [-\delta, \delta] \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| \leq \epsilon$ For any $L$.

Comment: A common mistake by students is to suppose that f'(x) must be continuous at x=0 in order for f'(0) to exist....